# Laravel update connection settings give error Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, laravel

I want to connect with database based on user, so i searched and found the following solution on stackoverflow.

```
DB::purge('mysql');
Artisan::call('config-cache');
//Artisan::call('cache:clear');
 
// Make sure to use the database name we want to establish a connection.
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.driver', 'mysql');
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.host', '127.0.0.1');
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', 'a2zfinal_2');
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.username', 'root');
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.password', ''); 

DB::reconnect('mysql');   
Schema::connection('mysql')->getConnection()->reconnect();
```

This work fine till here, when i query and print result, it fetch result from changed db.

```
$user = DB::Select('select * from user');
dd($user);
```

But when i try to user any other Modal e.g. Auth or redirect to any page to site, i get the following error

```
Auth::loginUsingId(19, TRUE);
```

Error

```
 E:\vhosts\a2zcost\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php

        }
     
        /**
         * Run an SQL statement and get the number of rows affected.
         *
         * @param  string  $query
         * @param  array   $bindings
         * @return int
         */
        public function affectingStatement($query, $bindings = [])
        {
            return $this->run($query, $bindings, function ($query, $bindings) {
                if ($this->pretending()) {
                    return 0;
                }
     
                // For update or delete statements, we want to get the number of rows affected
                // by the statement and return that back to the developer. We'll first need
                // to execute the statement and then we'll use PDO to fetch the affected.
                $statement = $this->getPdo()->prepare($query);
     
                $this->bindValues($statement, $this->prepareBindings($bindings));
     
                $statement->execute();
     
                $this->recordsHaveBeenModified(
                    ($count = $statement->rowCount()) > 0
                );
     
                return $count;
            });
        }
     
        /**
         * Run a raw, unprepared query against the PDO connection.
         *
         * @param  string  $query
         * @return bool
         */
        public function unprepared($query)

Arguments

    "Call to a member function prepare() on null"
```

What i am missing, as i stated above, i want to connect to other database and force login the user to new database attached

Comment: can you dd( $this->getPdo()); i think your getPdo return null;

Comment: u think $this->getPdo() will work here in controller ? i get  Method getPdo does not exist

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.8

Comment: are trying to build multi-tenant application? if yes , then did you make extra connection in `config/database.php` other than the the default mysql connection ?

Comment: @mahmudy-91 yes something like that,

Comment: I updated , laravel to 7x from 5.8 and the error i was getting is gone, my idea is user login , it take its related database settings from table and connect with it and use the site. do i have to define each connection string in the config or env ? there can be 100's of users? , what i have notices , when you connect with new db and go to another page, it again pick old as defined in config, do it lost config setting across requests ?

Comment: @IrfanZafar you will have to create a middleware that will reconnect to the right database on every request , and you will need to save the user database name in the "session" where you will get it in the middleware and reconnect to this database, if you need more clarification let me know and i will give you example middleware

Comment: @mahmudy-91 yes please, that will help me, Thanks

Comment: @mahmudy-91 please read my comments on below answers

Answer (score 1):

to overcome the issue of not connecting to the tenant database on later requests after the first one, you will have to use session to store the database name and handle this session with a middleware to always connect to the tenant database

create the trait TenantConnector

```
<?php

namespace App\Support;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

trait TenantConnector
{


    public function reconnect($databaseName)
    {
        // Erase the tenant connection, thus making Laravel get the default values all over again.


        DB::purge('tenant');
        // Make sure to use the database name we want to establish a connection.
        Config::set('database.connections.tenant.host', config('tenant.tenantdb_host'));
        Config::set('database.connections.tenant.port', config('tenant.tenantdb_port') );
        Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', $databaseName);
        Config::set('database.connections.tenant.username', config('tenant.tenantdb_username'));
        Config::set('database.connections.tenant.password', config('tenant.tenantdb_password'));

        // Rearrange the connection data

        DB::reconnect('tenant');
        session(['tenant' => $databaseName]);


    }
}
```

next the middleware you will need to handle session and reconnect to database on every request

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Models\Main\Workspace;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Support\TenantConnector;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class TenantMiddleware
{
    use TenantConnector;
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (($request->session()->get('tenant')) === null) {
            return redirect('/login');
        }

        $databaseName = $request->session()->get('tenant');
        $this->reconnect($databaseName);
        $request->session()->put('tenant', $databaseName);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

also you will need to create an extra config file for example `config/tenant.php`
where you will return an array of default configuration of the tenant connection
And Do not forget to add extra database connection in the `config/database.php` for that connection will be used for tenant databases

**EDIT TO `TenantcConnector` Trait**

```
<?php

namespace App\Support;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

trait TenantConnector
{


    public function reconnect($databaseName = null)
    {
        // Erase the tenant connection, thus making Laravel get the default values all over again.

        if($databaseName == null){

            DB::purge('main');
            DB::reconnect('main');
            session(['tenant' => null]);
            // assuming that main is
            // the name of your default database connection in config/database.php
        }else{
            DB::purge('tenant');
            // Make sure to use the database name we want to establish a connection.
            Config::set('database.connections.tenant.host', config('tenant.tenantdb_host'));
            Config::set('database.connections.tenant.port', config('tenant.tenantdb_port') );
            Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', $databaseName);
            Config::set('database.connections.tenant.username', config('tenant.tenantdb_username'));
            Config::set('database.connections.tenant.password', config('tenant.tenantdb_password'));

            // Rearrange the connection data

            DB::reconnect('tenant');
            session(['tenant' => $databaseName]);
        }


    }
}
```

then to connect to the main database inside any controller just `use TenantConnector` inside your class
and to connect to main database connection use `$this->reconnect()`

Comment: i implemented it like this as you stated, sometime it change database fine and sometimes i get error "Call to a member function prepare() on null",  when i see the config file in bootstrap i see, default connect changed to mysql2 , if i change it to mysql and save that file, page run. what i am missing here?

Comment: also what i have to do when i have to sign out, i have to sign out from parent (main) db, rather tenant db

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by config file in bootstrap, 
to know better where is the problem coming from you might need to use Logger class from facades and log the value of `session('tenant');` in `TenantMiddleware` and `TenantConnector` trait , also it will help better to know how you are using this `TenantConnector` trait in your code, as you will have to use it inside of the controller where you are logging in the user ,
you will also need to add extra code in your `TenantConnector` to use it to connect to main database when you need to , i will explain to you in the next comment.

Comment: in the answer above i will add extra code to the reconnect method inside `TenantConnector` Class to show how to reconnect to main database again

Answer (score -1):

i suggest you to extend your database environment.

in your env file :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret

DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql
DB_HOST_SECOND=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=database2
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=root
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=secret
```

and in your config/database

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => env('DB_CONNECTION'),
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
    'port'      => env('DB_PORT'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
],

'mysql2' => [
    'driver'    => env('DB_CONNECTION_SECOND'),
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST_SECOND'),
    'port'      => env('DB_PORT_SECOND'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME_SECOND'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECOND'),
],
```